# Maintain Scroll Position When Changing View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a recipe app with custom table views. The problem is, when entering a recipe view controller and returning to the recipe list view controller, it's not maintaining the previous scroll position. It's always back at the top.

I'm wondering if it's something in my code or if it's something I need to add to maintain the previous position.

This is the entire code from my recipe list view controller:

```
var recipeImgs: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "bananaPancakesCat.jpg")!,UIImage(named: "blackEyedPeaPattiesCat.jpg")!,UIImage(named: "blueberryMuffinsCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "buckwheatWafflesCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "cashewCreamCheeseCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "frenchToastCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "fruitSyrupCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "hashBrownsCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "proteinBarsCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "smoothieCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "tempehBaconCat.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "tofuQuicheCat.jpg")!]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecipesTableViewCell") as? RecipesTableViewCell {
        cell.configureCell(recipeImgs[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
        return cell

    } else {
        return RecipesTableViewCell()
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad) {
        return 120
    }
        return 90.0
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return recipeImgs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 0 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC1", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 1 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC2", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 2 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC3", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 3 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC4", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 4 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC5", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 5 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC6", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 6 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC7", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 7 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC8", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 8 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC9", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 9 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC10", sender: self)
    } else if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == 10 {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC11", sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "BRVC12", sender: self)
    }
}
```

And a video to demonstrate what's happening: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6jy37t97d1ihft/ScreenRecording_09-19-2017%2015%3A31.mp4?dl=0

Comment: you can keep a var in your viewController keeping the last offset.y position and after the load make scroll with `self.tableView.setContentOffset(<#T##contentOffset: CGPoint##CGPoint#>, animated: <#T##Bool#>)`

Comment: How are you returning to the original view controller? Are you sure you are not display a new list view controller instead of returning to the existing list view controller?

Comment: @rmaddy Storyboard segues. Is that my problem?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use storyboards. Just make sure your segue simply returns to the previous controller instead of to a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Add a variable to your view controller to keep track of the content offset of the scroll view. Set that variable in the `viewWillDisappear` method, and call the UITableView's `setContentOffset` method in the `viewWillAppear` method:

```
private var contentOffset: CGPoint?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let contentOffset = self.contentOffset {
        self.tableView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: true)
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    self.contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
}
```

Comment: But none of this is necessary. Simply going to another view controller and returning does not change the table view's scroll offset. There is more to the problem then simply reseting the scroll offset.

Comment: Woked. Thanks!!!